# Conditional Probability of two random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A fair coin is tossed with the outcome mapped into $X = 1$ for a head and $X = 0$ for a tail. If it comes up heads, then a fair die is tossed. The outcome of the die is denoted by $Y$ and is set equal to the number of dots observed. If the coin comes up tails, then we set $Y = 0$. Find the conditional PMF $p_{Y|X}[i, j]$ $\forall i, j$. Next, compute $P[Y = 1]$.

---

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable describing the outcome of the coin toss
  $$
  X =
  \begin{cases}
    0, & \text{if tails}\\
    1, & \text{if heads}
  \end{cases}
  $$
For a fair coin coin and that $S_X = \{0, 1\}$, the PMF of $X$ is
  $$
  p_X[i] =
  \begin{cases}
    0.5, & i = 0\\
    0.5, & i = 1
  \end{cases}
  $$
Let $Y$ be the discrete random variable describing the outcome of either the dice is rolled or $Y = 0$. Then $S_Y = \{0,\ldots, 6\}$
  $$
  Y =
  \begin{cases}
    0, & \text{if tails}\\
    \text{number observed}, & \text{if heads}
  \end{cases}
  $$
Then $p_{Y|X}[j, i] = P[Y|X]p_X[i] = P[Y = j\cap X = i]$.
  $$
  p_{Y|X}[j, i] =
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{7}, & i, j = 0\\
    \frac{1}{7}, & i = 1, j = 1, 2, \ldots, 6\\
  \end{cases}
  $$
Then $P[Y = 1] = p_{X, Y}[1, 1] = \frac{1}{7}$.

---

The book says $P[Y = 0, X = 0] = 1$ and $P[Y = j, X = 1] = 1/6$ for all $j$.  This would mean the sum of the joint PMF is 2 though.  Finally, it has that $P[Y = 1] = 1/12$.

Is this correct?  If so, how is it obtained?

Comment: Probably when they write $P(Y=0,X=0)=1$ they mean the conditional probability of $Y$ being equal to $0$ given that $X=0$. Perhaps it is a typo or a bad notation.

Comment: @Stefanos is my work then correct for the PMF?  What about `P[Y = 1]`?

Comment: Why $1/7$ and not $1/6$? How do you come up with $1/7$. No, it is not correct. For $P(Y=1)$ see my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer. Is it ok now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mistake to confuse the random variables $Y|X=0$ and $Y|X=1$. They are two different "objects". Given that $X=0$ then $Y=0$ with probability $1$, thus $$p_{Y|X=0}(i|x)=\begin{cases} 1, & i=1 \\ 0, & \text{else }\end{cases}$$
On the other hand, given that $X=1$ then $Y$ is the result of a fair dice, thus $Y|X=1$ is uniformly distributed on the set $\{1,2, \ldots, 6\}$, i.e.
$$p_{Y|X=1}(i|x)=\begin{cases} 1/6, & i\in\{1,2\ldots,6\} \\ 0, & \text{else }\end{cases}$$

For the last part of your question $$P(Y=1)=P(Y=1|X=0)P(X=0)+P(Y=1|X=1)P(X=1)=0\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\dfrac{1}{12}$$

Note that $P(Y=1)$ refers to a calculation **before** the result of $X$ has become known, so you must condition on it's result. Therefore it is not the same as $P(Y=1|X=1)$.

Comment: Is my PMF correct?

Comment: See my edit. Is it know ok? You should have 2 pmf's, not 1 pmf.

Comment: Isnt it true that $\sum P[Y=j|X=i] = 1$?  In this case, it sums to two not one then.

Comment: No, it is not true. It is true that $\sum_{i,j} P(Y=j|X=i)P(X=i)=1$. You forget the probability that $X=i$ in your formula, and in particular you confuse the random variables $Y|X=0$ and $Y|X=1$. You have that $\sum_{j}P(Y=j|X=1)=1$ and $\sum_{j}P(Y=j|X=0)=1$  or as I wrote before $\sum_{i,j}P(Y=j|X=i)P(X=i)=1$